# graphing large amounts of data on one chart visual studio

Tags: c#, visual-studio, charts

[Immage of chart when program ran and bottom "GRAPH" is pressed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9wmuj.png)

how can i make it so that data does not appear at bottom of chart?

```
 string path = @"c:\users\thebi\desktop\code\justins sample c# code\csv test (writing while open in matlab)\csv vs\csv test\bin\debug\outputfile.txt";
        int time = 0;
        string[] readText = File.ReadAllLines(path);
        int sizeofarray;
        sizeofarray = readText.Length;
        for (int i = 0; i < sizeofarray; i++)
        {
            chart1.Series["Series1"].Points.AddXY(readText[i], time);
            time++;
        }
```

Comment: Your code isn't reading CSV values, it's passing the entire line as a single label to the chart

Comment: What chart are you using? What does the data look like? And which columns do you want to display? Each column is a separate series of values. This means that once you load the CSV data into a DataTable, 2D array or List<T> of strongly typed objects, you need to add one series for every column. Some charts can bind directly to DataTable or Lists, and generate series from columns or properties

Comment: Note: When you add x-values as strings they will appear in the label but otherwise are lost, ie the x-values are set to zero. You need to split the columns and transform the parts  to numbers to create a proper chart..

Comment: Did you solve the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Although your question is not clear, I assume you want to get rid of the long label of data point in X Axis. You can try;

```
chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.LabelStyle.Enabled = false;
```